# Visual DataFlex: call WebService from the web page

Tags: dataflex

I have the web service and generated class for it. I can use this generated class in windows application as it described in Help. The question is: how can I use this generated class in the web project? (the analogous actions - creating object and use its functions -, as it was in windows app,  are not worked)

Comment: What happens? Do you get compiler errors?

Comment: when you include the package you should be able to use it. Any error messages? Does the WebService run locally? You might not be able to run two webservices at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Dataflex questions are best asked at: http://support.dataaccess.com

There are a couple of possibilities.

Your class may not be cWebService or you have not included it as part of a web project. 
For web services to be available, they MUST be part of a web project. This will usually be called webapp.src.

For functions to be available to the web service, you need to decorate them as "published"

e.g.

```
{ Published = True  }
{ Description = "SOAP Hello World function definition."  }
Function HelloWorld Returns String
    Function_Return "HELLO WORLD"
End_Function
```

Those top two lines make sure that the function is available as a SOAP or web service call.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to answer so late, I hope you've already solved it.

There's actually a tutorial section for this in the VDF Help under Tutorials > Quick Start > Consuming Your First Web Service > Consuming a Web Service in a Web Application.